# Bloquear o acesso a páginas que contenham ".php" com o HTACCESS

Tags: php, htaccess

Quero bloquear o acesso direto a arquivos que terminem com a extensão `.php`.

Suponhamos que eu tenha uma página chamada `teste.php`. Se o usuário tentar acessá-la por `teste.php` ele irá receber um 404. O único jeito para a página ser acessada seria `teste`, sem a extensão `.php`.

Teria como fazer isso com .HTACCESS?

---

#### EDIT 1

Estrutura das pastas:

```
 .htaccess
 index.php
 contact.php
 error
  │ 404.php
  │ 500.php
  │ ops.php
```

Comment: você não acha melhor redireciona-lo com um simples header("Location") no topo de cada página .php?

Comment: Também tenho essa dúvida, eu acho mais conveniente colocar a página de erro 404.

Comment: @AndreiCoelho Seria melhor ir para o 404 mesmo.

Comment: Eu não entendo muito de htacces... por isso pergunto se poderia ser de um jeito e tal... pois bem... E oque você acha de analisar a url e verificar se existe alguma extensão .php.. se existir mostre a página 404

Comment: É perfeitamente possivel, se bem que o melhor seria o 403 que significa, acesso restrito. Você quer direcionar todos acessos para o index.php?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Pode ser também para o `index`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(?:GET|POST)\ /.*\.php\ HTTP.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ http://seusite.com/erro404 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Essa a que mais se aproximou em um resultado aceitável. Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

Tente uma dessas opções:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

ou essa:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [L, QSA]
```

e essa eu uso no ZF2 talvez tire algo de exemplo:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)(.+)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Nenhuma dessas funcionou... :(

Comment: Tem como postar a estrutura de pastas e arquivos?

Answer (score 1):

Você também pode fazer isso no próprio PHP, podendo assim, escolher exibir ou não o arquivo.

Exemplo:

```
if (basename($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]) == "nome_do_arquivo.php") {

    echo "acesso nao permitido..."; //ou um header("location $url_destino");

} else {

    //mostra o conteudo

}
```